# Curl usage in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, curl

I have tried this command in Jenkins pipeline script

sh ‘curl ${BUILD_URL}consoleText —-output ${WORKSPACE}/logs/log.txt’

But it’s not resolving the WORKSPACE variable.Any idea how to proceed.

Comment: @T M Suhas does this works for you

Comment: please try  """  .... """ (tripple quote syntax) or "..."  double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in below way:

```
def Workspace=env.WORKSPACE

sh "<Yourcommand> ${Workspace}"
```